# Is base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) necessary?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm overriding `OnModelCreating`, and in the method there's the line `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Looking at code samples and manuals on how to implement this, I get confused as to wether I need it or not. Sometimes it's there, sometimes not. Sometimes at the beginning of the method, other times at the end.

What should I do with it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating), it doesn't matter if you inherit directly from the `DbContext` class:

> This method is called when the model for a derived context has been initialized, but before the model has been locked down and used to initialize the context. **The default implementation of this method does nothing**, but it can be overridden in a derived class such that the model can be further configured before it is locked down.

In other words, since is does nothing **by definition**, calling `base.OnModelCreating` is not necessary, but at the same time will not hurt if called - that's why *Sometimes it's there, sometimes not. Sometimes at the beginning of the method, other times at the end.*

Comment: I get it. Still, why would it call it when it does nothing? I mean, I get that the override gives the modelBuilder in which we can put further configurations. But why the call to base? Or in other words, what happens with the modelBuilder we pass in to it. It sounds all so... useless :-)

Comment: That's the point. When you have a base `virtual` method, there must be some documentation explaining the requirements of calling that method when you override it, like if you need to call it at all, of if you need to call it at the beginning or at the end. Here the documentation states the method does nothing, so there is no requirement - you can call it at any place of your override if you wish or you can not call it at all. Once you know it does nothing **by definition**, you'd probably would not call it:)

Comment: In OO you call the base class to make sure, its declared behaviour is met. Whatever that behaviour may be. You don't look at what base does in detail. Maybe someday it decides to do something other then nothing or to do nothing in a different way. Therefore I would call it. The question wether to put it first or last remains, though.

Comment: It is required in an ASP.Net project that uses ASP.Net Identity.

Comment: @BenjaminRay Yes, it is - when you inherit  some of the `IdentityDbContext` base classes. Here I'm talking about the `DbContext` class. Each derived class used as base should define if the base calls are needed and whether before or after the overriding code.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are right. I didn't even notice that a model using Identity inherits `IdentityDbContext` instead of the usual `DbContext`.

Answer (score 4):

Here what says [**Pawel Kadluczka - MSFT**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/pawel%20kadluczka%20-%20msft/?ws=usercard-mini) ...

> At the moment it does not really matter. Both OnModelCreating and Seed
>   methods don't have any implementation (i.e. the bodies of the
>   functions are empty) in their base classes. Therefore calling into the
>   base class is basically a no-op. I don't think there are any plans to
>   change it (especially for Seed method - how we would know what data to
>   put in the database?)
>
> In general protected methods can have some implementation in base
>   classes. In that case this is up to the developer who derives from
>   such a class to decide whether s/he would like to take advantage of
>   the functionality provided in the method in the base class or not. If
>   the developer thinks that s/he only would like to add something to the
>   functionality provided by the method in the base class s/he would call
>   into this method. Otherwise s/he would not call into the method of the
>   base class and would provide all the required functionality in the
>   method on the derived class.

***Reference :*** [**Link**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d233c6c0-cec9-4feb-82f5-20fbada776d4/code-first-should-we-always-call-the-base-after-overriding-seed-and-onmodelcreating?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Comment: What does say a person (being MSFT or not) really doesn't matter. The only important is what does say **the official documentation** (and if it's wrong, then that's a bug that has to be reported and fixed - apparently this is not the case here).

Comment: hmm..both are same here :D @IvanStoev

Answer (score 4):

When you override the creation you override the creation of the identity creation too. If you have not inherited any IdentityDbContext you don't need it but if you have used Identity then you have to invoke the identity's implementation too. So to invoke the identity's implementation use base.OnModelCreating(builder); So If you override the creation of Identity then Identity loses its configuration. So you run the base to preserve the creation of Identity too.

Answer (score 1):

I have just begun a ASP.NET MVC5 project and based on this thread I commented "base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)" out.
Then I wanted to update table names etc. for the EF6 standard DbContext and when executing 'add-migration Abc' the console kept throwing this error at me:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> xxx.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> xxx.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

After a bit of struggle, I tried un-commenting "base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)" and that made it all work as intended.

I have not found out exactly why, but it appears that this line of code is necessary in some cases.

Comment: Were you inheriting from `DbContext` or `IdentityDbContext`? That would likely make a difference.

Comment: @Sinjai: In this particular project I inherit from `IdentityDbContext`. In the end this class inherits from `DbContext` where `OnModelCreating` is defined, so still not entirely clear to me what purpose it serves, but if it's needed for migrations to work, that's a mystery I can live with for now :-)

Comment: That would do it. As the selected answer correctly notes, `DbContext` does not provide an implementation for `OnModelCreating()`, but `IdentityDbContext` *does*. So if you don't call `base.OnModelCreating()` in your subclass, the identity relationships won't be configured (and therefore may cause errors), as you've discovered.