# Map Id to ClassName+Id field in the datatable in EF5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, mapping, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

Having a EFCore-5.0 application I try to map the `Foo`'s class `Id` property to the `FooId` field name in the DB.

I try (following [this](https://imar.spaanjaars.com/588/prefixing-id-columns-with-the-table-name-in-entity-framework) old link) to map it in my `OnModelCreating` of the DbContext

```
modelBuilder.Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
    .Configure(p => p.IsKey().HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name + "Id"));
```

However it tells me

> Error CS1061  'ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'Properties' and no accessible extension method 'Properties' accepting
> a first argument of type 'ModelBuilder' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @Patrick Xavier Silerio said,what you did is used in EF not EF Core.

In EF Core,you need use Data Annotation or Fluent API to configure the column name:

Data Annotation:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Column("FooId")]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .Property(b => b.Id)
        .HasColumnName("FooId");
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-names

If you want to change all the `Id` to `ClassName+Id`,change like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{           
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name)
                   .Property("Id").HasColumnName(entity.GetTableName()+"Id");
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way, in the last code, you did remove the call to base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)... is it OK if I am beginner just to replace the base method with the code you provided?

Comment: It's OK.I think you need refer to this answer which explain perfectly:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39576336/11398810.

Answer (score 0):

`ModelBuilder.Properties()` as used in the link you mentioned is from Entity Framework 6, and not for EF Core. I believe that's the crux of your problem.

You can refer to: [Set column names during OnModelCreating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452732/set-column-names-during-onmodelcreating),  [Remove tableprefix with .net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054527/remove-tableprefix-with-net-core), and [EF Core 2.0 OwnsOne column prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187344/ef-core-2-0-ownsone-column-prefix)